# What to do with non-reproducible unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

As of time of writing this, there are 250+ stale, unanswered questions.

It is fair to note that some of these unanswered questions are still genuine and valuable questions. They simply have not been answered. We should keep these questions and can address them in a separate post.

However, in this post, I would like to address stale non-reproducible unanswered questions. Questions that are missing a reproducible example for us to replicate and provide a solution. These are questions that without a reproducible example it is like taking a shot in the dark. Often you will see in the comments: "try this..." or additional follow up questions asking for more context into the problem. Here is an [example](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/how-does-offence-pallet-work).

My proposal is twofold:

1. Go through all 250+ unanswered questions, identify questions that fall in this category. Follow up with a comment: "[Please provide a replicable example...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Give the author 1 month to provide an example. If the example has not been provided - close the question due to "Needs details or clarity".
2. Be proactive. From now on, we immediately identify these types of questions and [ask for a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the comment of the question. Shawn and Dan do a good job of this already. However, let's make it a community effort. If the author does not produce a reproducible example in 1 month's time --> close.

Additionally, me or whoever does the grooming, can post a list of questions that have met the 1 month mark and will be closed here in a meta post so there is complete transparency on the questions that will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not reproducable and stale, then closing them seems the best option. Having them open for a while before closing is good because then there's a chance that someone else googling for the same error message will get a search hit and might be able to shed a bit more light on the problem.

There's lots of questions about substrate that haven't been answered yet and that's ok. Possibly we'll see that some have been answered later and in that case the original unanswered question can be marked as a dupe.